# How Do I Render Form Attributes Manually in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to render the **name** attribute manually.

```html
{% for language in form.languages %}
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" id="{{ language.id_for_label }}" name="{{ language.field.name }}" type="checkbox">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ language.id_for_label }}">{{ language.choice_label }}</label>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Everything gets rendered nicely except the name attribute of the input tag.

form.languages is a ManyToManyField shown on my form as a ModelMultipleChoiceField using the following code in my forms.py.

```py
languages = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
  queryset=Language.objects.all(),
  widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
)
```

**EDIT:** Found the culprit, apparently I need a *value* attribute, not a *name* attribute, now I just need to find a way to get the value into the template.

Comment: Could you try whether `name="{language.html_name}"` resolves your problem? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.html_name

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it but it didn't help, when I'm inspecting the element the name attribute is empty (Not set to anything), aka same issue I was having.

Comment: Might help to see your model for Language?  What attribute in that model are you trying to display?

Comment: I solved it, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. What I did was use **{{ language.data.value }}**.